# Bash script is producing 'sh: write error: Function not implemented'

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that reports on traffic usage on routers running DD-WRT, Openwrt, Turris, etc. (see http://usage-monitoring.com)

Occasionally, a slew of error messages get written the PuTTY window:

> sh: write error: Function not implemented

The script does send output to a log file on a USB attached to the router...
The logging function looks something like this: (BTW - all of the _variables are define properly elsewhere in the code)

```
send2log_1_2 ">>> Starting main loop" 1

send2log_1_2()
{   #_enableLogging=1 & _log2file=2 (both file & screen)
    local ts=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
    [ "$2" -ge "$_loglevel" ] && echo -e "$ts\t$2\t$1" >> $_logfilename
    [ "$2" -ge "2" ] && alertfile "$1"
    [ "$2" -ge "$_scrlevel" ] && echo -e "$ts $2 $1" >&2
}
```

Is there anything obvious here that could be the cause of the errors?  Otherwise I have no idea of how to track down the issue.

Let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: Presumably this is coming back from a syscall -- ie. the driver layer is returning ENOSYS. That makes this very, *very* specific to the device to which you're actually writing.

Comment: @Jens, ...indeed, the `function` keyword isn't specified in `/bin/sh`, but that won't be part of a `write()` error.

Comment: ...by the way, `echo -e` *really* shouldn't be used when your shell is `sh`. See the [POSIX `echo` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- `-e` isn't specified at all, and in the APPLICATION USAGE section, folks who need either the effects of `echo -n` or backslash-escape handling are instructed to use `printf` instead.

Comment: Run the script with `set -x` added near the top and show us the part when it errors.

Comment: @Jens, ...we'll need more than just the part where it errors, if it's writing to a previously-redirected file descriptor; we'll also need the part where that FD was opened. Suggesting a `PS4` that logs the line number would be helpful. (That said, I have actual work to be doing, so I can't hang around this question much longer to see it through myself).

Comment: @Al_C, ...btw, you say "bash" in the title and have a "bash" tag, but your error messages specify "sh". sh and bash are very different shells; be sure your script is running with the one you *think* it's using.

Comment: @Jens - thanks for the responses.  I'm operating well beyond my level of expertise here... I don't expect that set -x will help because of the volume of output it'll generate... unless there's a way to direct the output to a file.  PS4?!? sounds helpful but I have no idea how to add that